# Шаговый движок странно себя ведёт при управлении с Python через Firmata

Tags: python, arduino

```
import pyfirmata
import time

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('COM3')
board.digital[8].write(1)

step = board.get_pin('d:5:o')
dir = led = board.get_pin('d:8:o')
dir.write(0)
while True:
    step.write(1)
    step.write(0)
```

Сейчас движок просто крутится вроде как на максимальной скорости хотя тут ведь нет задержек и движок по идее должен просто визжать но он почему то нормально работает. Плюс к этому если поставить задержку причем не важно с каким значением то движок просто очень медленно крутится. Я попробовал поставить задержку в пол секунды но по факту это скорее целая секунда. И плюс к этому движок периодически то пропускает шаг то ли наоборот делает очень маленький интервал между шагами но суть в том что движок дёргается. Юзаю Arduino UNO, через Arduino IDE всё работает отлично так что проблема точно не в железе

Comment: Не понятно в чем заключается вопрос.

Comment: @ГеннадийП двигатель не реагирует на изменение задержки между шагами